# How can I resolve this error and work smoothly in deep learning?

Tags: pandas, performance, machine-learning, deep-learning

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs_size = 25
history = model.fit(data_train, validation_data=data_val, epochs=epochs_size)

***error is :***

---

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 4
1 epochs_size = 25
2 # history = model.fit(data_train, validation_data=data_val, epochs=epochs_size)
----> 4 history = model.fit(data_train, validation_data=data_val, epochs=epochs_size)

File C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
123 finally:
124     del filtered_tb

File C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
51 try:
52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
56   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node sequential_1_1/conv2d_3_1/Reshape defined at (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main

File "", line 88, in _run_code

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 18, in

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1075, in launch_instance

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 739, in start

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 205, in start

File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 639, in run_forever

File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1985, in _run_once

File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 545, in dispatch_queue

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 534, in process_one

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 437, in dispatch_shell

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 362, in execute_request

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 778, in execute_request

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 449, in do_execute

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 549, in run_cell

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3075, in run_cell

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3130, in _run_cell

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3334, in run_cell_async

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3517, in run_ast_nodes

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3577, in run_code

File "C:\Users\tayya\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10076\2761535915.py", line 4, in

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 325, in fit

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 118, in one_step_on_iterator

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 106, in one_step_on_data

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 57, in train_step

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 814, in **call**

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 48, in **call**

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 202, in call

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 194, in call

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\function.py", line 151, in _run_through_graph

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 578, in call

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 814, in **call**

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 48, in **call**

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\convolutional\base_conv.py", line 233, in call

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\numpy.py", line 4507, in reshape

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\numpy.py", line 1545, in reshape

Input to reshape is a tensor with 0 values, but the requested shape has 16
[[{{node sequential_1_1/conv2d_3_1/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_5017]

Comment: please edit your post and include lines that are code or error as code block